# how to combine query result into jQuery easyUI Datagrid?

Tags: jquery

In My scenario, i need to use jQuery easyUI datagrid plugin. And after search jQuery easyUI datagrid api document, need to use "url" parameter to invoke my json query result. And the currently, my query result is already json format in my apex class.

following is example from jQuery easyUI datagrid:

```
<table id="db"
       class="easyui-datagrid"
       title="CheckBox Selection on DataGrid" 
       style="width:700px;height:250px"
       data-options="rownumbers:true,singleSelect:true,
       url:'***../datagrid/datagrid_data1.json***'">
```

But, i don't know that what value for url if i use apex class?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use the `url` property, since the plugin doesn't know how to set the HTTP authorization header with the session ID, so a call to the REST API or an Apex REST method wouldn't work.

Assuming you're creating a Visualforce page, use the `data` property with a merge field, and, if necessary, implement a method in the controller that returns the JSON result. Like this...

```
<table id="db"
   class="easyui-datagrid"
   title="CheckBox Selection on DataGrid" 
   style="width:700px;height:250px"
   data-options="rownumbers:true,singleSelect:true,
   data:{!queryResult}">
```

In the controller...

```
public String getQueryResult() {
    String result = // Whatever...
    return result;
}
```

Given the potential problems with quotes, it is probably safer to create the datagrid with JavaScript:

```
<table id="db"
   class="easyui-datagrid"
   title="CheckBox Selection on DataGrid" 
   style="width:700px;height:250px">

<script>
// Put this somewhere sensible, like in the jQuery $(document).ready handler
$('#dg').datagrid({  
    rownumbers: true,
    singleSelect: true,
    data: {!queryResult}
});
</script>
```

You may also need to define a `columns` property.

Comment: hi metadaddy, firstly many thanks give some idea. but, i also has other similar question. if we combine queryResult, how to implement CRUD with jquery?

Answer (score 1):

This is something I have used in the past.  This is using a custome object Commitment__c, but you can get the basic idea.  Hopefully this helps

```
<script>
    jQuery(function(){      

        var commdata;           
        commdata = '{!commJSON}';


        jQuery("#commList").jqGrid({ 
            datatype: 'jsonstring', 
            datastr: commdata,
            sortable:true,
            colNames:['Due','Account','Owner', 'Name'], 
            colModel:[                  
                    {name:'Due', sortable:true, sorttype: "date", index:'Due_Date__c', align:'center'},
                    {name:'Account', sortable:true, index:'Account__c'},
                    {name:'Owner', sortable:true, sorttype: "text", index:'Owner__r.Alias', align:'center'},
                    {name:'Name', index:'Name', sortable:true, sorttype: "text" },              
            ],
            rowNum:10, 
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            loadonce: false, 
            viewrecords: true, 
            sortorder: "asc",
            sortname: 'Due_Date__c', 
            caption:'',
            hidegrid: false,
            height:'100%',
            autoencode : false,
            emptyrecords: 'No records to display.'
        });

});
</script>
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page>
<apex:form >            
    <div style="width:100%" id="commPanel">
        <div style="margin:0; width:98%">
            <table id="commList" class="commList" style="width:100%;cursor:pointer"></table> 
        </div>              
    </div>
</apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class myCommitmentsPortletController {

    public string commJSON  { get; set; }
    public Commitment__c[] myComms  { get; set; }

    public myCommitmentsPortletController() {
        try {
            myComms = [select id, Name, Due_Date__c, Status__c, Account__c, Account__r.Name, Owner__c, Owner__r.Alias
                from Commitment__c
                where Owner__c = :Userinfo.getuserid()
                and Status__c <> 'Completed'
                order by Due_Date__c asc];
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }

        commJSON = getJSonString();
    }

    public String getJSonString(){
        string jsonstring; 

        if(this.myComms != null && this.myComms.size() > 0) {
            jSonString = '{"page":1,"total":' + ( 1 + ( myComms.size() / 10 )) + ',"records":' + String.valueOf(myComms.size()) + ',"rows":[';

            for(Commitment__c c : myComms ) {
                jSonString += '{"id":"' + c.id + '","cell":[';
                jsonString += JqGridDataController.parseCell(c.Due_Date__c);
                jsonString += JqGridDataController.parseCell('<a href=/'+ c.Account__c + '>'+ c.Account__r.Name +'</a>');
                jsonString += JqGridDataController.parseCell(c.Owner__r.Alias);
                jsonString += JqGridDataController.parseCell('<a href=/'+ c.Id + '>' + c.Name + '</a>');                
                jsonString = jsonString.subString(0,jsonString.length() - 1);
                jsonString += ']},';
            }

            jsonString = jsonString.subString(0,jsonString.length() - 1);
            jsonString += ']}';
        }
        else {
            //no records were retrieved
            jsonString = '{"page":"1","total":1,"records":"' + String.valueOf('0') + '","rows":[';
            jsonString += '],"userdata":{"amount":3220,"tax":342,"total":3564,"name":"Totals:"}}';
        }
        return jSonString;
    }
}
```

And the helper Class

```
public with sharing class JqGridDataController {

    public static String parseCell(Object pField) { 
        String ret = checkForDate(pField);
        if(ret == 'null'){
            ret = 'null,';
        }else{
            ret = ret.replaceAll('"','\\\'' ); // get content produces quote chars \"  
            ret = ret.replaceAll( '&','&amp;');// we need to escape these in the node value
            ret = ret.replaceAll('\n',' '); // must use ALL since many new line may get 
            ret = ret.replaceAll('\r',' '); // get these also!
            ret = ret.replaceAll('\'', '&rsquo;'); // get content produces single quote chars \'      
                ret = '"' + ret + '",';
        }
        return ret ; 
    }

    private static String checkForDate(Object pField){
        String ret = '' + pField;
        Date tmpDate;
        DateTime tmpDateTime;

        try{
            tmpDateTime = DateTime.valueOf(ret);
            ret = tmpDateTime.format('M/dd/yyyy');
        }catch(TypeException eDate){
            try{
                tmpDateTime = DateTime.valueOf(ret);
                ret = tmpDateTime.format('M/dd/yyyy h:mm a');
            }catch(TypeException eDateTime){
                //do nothing because ret is already a string.
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    static testMethod void test() {
        String parsedCell = JqGridDataController.parseCell('abc&&&$@1<>""');
        System.assertEquals('"abc&amp;&amp;&amp;$@1<>&rsquo;&rsquo;",',parsedCell);
        DateTime dt = System.NOW();
        String parsedDate = JqGridDataController.parseCell(dt);
        System.assertNotEquals(null,parsedDate);
    }

}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Dunc44, but, i also has other similar question. how to implement CRUD with jquery?

Comment: For this you could use javascript remoting.  Take a look at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm

Comment: Are you means, use jquery invoke javascript remote to do CRUD?